# Get Internet Explorer shorcuts from .mui file

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, internationalization, keyboard-shortcuts, autoit

I'm trying to make an AutoIT script to automatize certain tasks. The problem is that I'm basing most of the IE control on the use of shortcuts. Shortcuts depend on the IE language settings so, in order to make an international implementation, I should know which are the current hotkeys given the current IE language packages. I understand that this can be done using the .mui files that come in the IE language packages, but I'm not finding where these shortcut settings are. Some of the .mui files have entries that clearly represent shortcuts, but they seem to be the same in every language package... Any ideas?

Comment: Is it not possible to use the IE automation library that comes with AutoIt?

Comment: Not really. I'm still trying to get this done... Anyone?